# Font-Face - Can you reference the pathway in HTML?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I'm learning about font-Face for the first time and I can't seem to find my solution anywhere..

I want to make just one H1 tag to have a custom font-face, i.e one style that I downloaded and put into a folder called **/fonts**.

I only want it to appear in this ONE H1 tag, so I want to go in via the HTML to do this instead of making a new Div class.

The name of the style is "Sweetly Broken Bold"

Is there a way to reference the font-face within HTML from within the H1 tag itself ?

I cant seem to figure it out...

Comment: You don't need an extra div, just give the `h1` itself a class, and then make that class use the font you need.

Answer (score 0):

So you'd import the Font into your HTML first

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Then for the H1 that you're looking to have just the font for without making a new div you'd do:

```
<h1 style="font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;">Hi!</h1>
```

You'd just change the font-family item to whatever the item is for "Sweetly Broken Bold".

If you're using a local font, you'd just change the Import from what's above to

```
<link href='folder/localfont.ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Answer (score 0):

1.) Assign a new class to that particular h1 tag, for example

```
<h1 class="xyz1">[...Header Text...]</h1>
```

2.) In the CSS (stylesheet or `<style>` tag in your page), create a CSS rule like this:

```
.xyz1 {
  font-family: 'Sweetly Broken Bold'; 
}
```

ADDITION:

3.) Instead of #1 and #2, you can also write this in the HTML code (= no need for extra style definitions):

```
<h1 style="font-family: 'Sweetly Broken Bold';">[...Header Text...]</h1>
```

Comment: added another way which involves just *one* step instead of two

Comment: with the note that inlining style is a horrible idea and if you're using CSS already, just use classes, of course =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans yes, I agree, but the OP wrote: "I want to go in via the HTML to do this instead of making a new Div class", so i added this as an alternative solution.

Comment: fair enough, but it's okay to tell someone "unless you can explain why you want that, what you want is bad" =P (you don't need a `div` class if you want to style and `h1`, maybe they though they needed a wrapping `<div class="..."><h1>...</h1></div>`)